# Avoiding line breaks in HTML output of PHP

Tags: php, line, output, line-breaks

Here I have my print function:

```
<?php
// little helper function to print the results
function printTag($tags) {
    foreach($tags as $t) {
            echo '<span class="' . $t['tag'] . '">';
            echo $t['token'] . "/" . $t['tag'];
            echo '</span>';
            echo " ";

    }
}

$tagger = new PosTagger('lexicon.txt');
?>
```

And here is what I'm outputting from an HTML form:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submitbutton'] == "Submit") {
//Check whether the form has been submitted
$tags = $tagger->tag($_POST['texttotag']);
printTag($tags);
}
?>
```

My problem is, the output in the browser results in strange line breaks in the middle of some of my `<span>` like so:

```
<span class="VB">Enter/VB</span> <span class="PRP$">your/PRP$</span> <span class="NN
">text/NN
</span> <span class="TO">to/TO</span> <span class="NN">tag/NN</span> <span class="RB
">here/RB
</span>
```

This means my CSS definitions don't apply to the "interrupted" spans. Any idea why this is happening and how I can stop it? I've had a good look around and haven't been able to find cause/solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `$t['tag']` variable includes a line-break.

You can get rid of that using `trim($t['tag'])` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out, where exactly in the OP's code, the line break is. Can you elaborate on that for me please?

Comment: @Fred From the look of the html, after the tag, so they would be `NN\n` and `RB\n`. Note that not all tags include a line-break, just 2 in this case.

Comment: @jeroen Ah yes, I see it now. I wasn't into the HTML itself, silly me. Thank you, cheers - ~(`+1`)~

Comment: @user1888121 By the way, I would get rid of the line-breaks as soon as the tags are stored (in a database I assume...).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the $t['tag'] in printTag function contains line break character. You can use str_replace function to remove these characters like:

```
function printTag($tags) {
    foreach($tags as $t) {
        echo '<span class="' . $t['tag'] . '">';

        $ttag = str_replace('\n','',$t['tag']);
        $ttag = str_replace('\r','',$ttag);

        echo $t['token'] . "/" . $ttag;
        echo '</span>';
        echo " ";

    }
}
```

Comment: You could learn from `jeroen's` answer (I have). It is so much more compact and elegant. ;-)

Comment: @fred There are many ways of doing the same thing. I appreciate jeroen answer.

Comment: Yes indeed; it's always a good thing learning from people that have more experience. I learn all the time, and that is the beauty of it, it's learning from our mistakes and from others'. Cheers.